# To get the selected values using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to get the selected value from a table using jquery am dont get any values, kindly help me out

Here is my code:

```
$(this).parents("tr:first").find("td:nth-child(1).option:selected").text();

<td>
     <select id="grams">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option value="100">100g</option>
         <option value="250">250g</option>
         <option value="500">500g</option>
     </select>
</td>
```

Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: $("#grams option:selected").val();

Comment: var value= $("#grams option:selected").text();

Comment: Why can't you select directly to `#grams`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("#grams").val();
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SMLLa/) is a quick fiddle for this.

Comment: if there is two selection box with same id then how to get the selected value?    for example  
    <td>
     <select id="grams">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option value="100">100g</option>
         <option value="250">250g</option>
         <option value="500">500g</option>
     </select>
    </td>

    <td>
     <select id="grams">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option value="100">100g</option>
         <option value="250">250g</option>
         <option value="500">500g</option>
     </select>
    </td>

Comment: The `ID`s are meant to be unique. If one ID is repeated then you have an invalid document at the very first place.

Answer (score 2):

To Read Select Option Value use

```
$('#grams').val();
```

To Set Select Option Value use

```
$('#grams').val('newValue');
```

To Read Selected Text use

```
$('#grams>option:selected').text();
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try with these as you have specified an id to the element you can get the value straight from that:

```
$('#grams').val(); // gets the current option value
$('#grams option:selected').val(); // gives you the selected option value
```

and if you want it to get through binding the `change` event:

```
// with a selector's context way

$('#grams').on('change', function(e){
   console.log($('option:selected', this).val());
});

// with find() method of jQuery

$('#grams').on('change', function(e){
   console.log($(this).find('option:selected').val());
});
```